# Laravel blade: Can you yield a default partial

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

If I have a layout called `RightSideBar.blade.php` in `Laravel blade`, one area `yield('content')` and the other `yield('sidebar')`.

Is there a built in way to display a `default partial` if the view that is extending `RightSideBar` does not have a `section('sidebar')`?

I know you can pass a **value** by **default**, just wondering if there is a way to make default a partial.

Comment: Was simple really, although the docs specified a default only as a string you can in fact pass a view @yield('sidebar', \View::make('defaultSidebar'))

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Yes you can pass a default

Looking at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#template-inheritance)

`@yield('sidebar', 'Default Content');`

Which basically puts a default output when the child template does not have `@section('sidebar')`

Comment: this is not correct. to render a partial you cant just pass a string, instead do as @user3238419 suggested above, doing View::make(pathtoview)

Comment: I think OP has mentioned that he is aware that he can do it as mentioned on the comment. Was my answer wrong because I stated an example as a string and not a blade?

Comment: yes because he explicitly said: "I know you can pass a value by default..", and also the question is asking for a partial, not a plain string.

Comment: problem with this approach is html is escaped

Answer (score 20):

Most of the time we want multiple line default content, we can use this syntax:

```
@section('section')
    Default content
@show
```

For example I have this in the template file:

```
@section('customlayout')
    <article class="content">
        @yield('content')
    </article>
@show
```

You can see the difference between @show and @stop/@endsection: the above code is equivalent to the one below:

```
@section('customlayout')
    <article class="content">
        @yield('content')
    </article>
@stop

@yield('customlayout')
```

In the other view files I can either set the content only:

```
@section('content')
    <p>Welcome</p>
@stop
```

Or I can also set a different layout:

```
@section('content')
    <p>Welcome</p>
@stop
@section('defaultlayout')
    <div>
        @yield('content')
    </div>
@stop
```

The @stop is equivalent as the @endsection.

Answer (score 17):

Although the docs specifies a default only as a string you can in fact pass a view

```
@yield('sidebar', \View::make('defaultSidebar'))
```

Answer (score 9):

Laravel 5.2 added a `@hasSection` directive that checks if a section is defined in a view.
It's not mentioned in 5.3 or 5.4 docs for some reason.

```
@hasSection('sidebar')
    @yield('sidebar')
@else
    @yield('default-sidebar')
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested in **Laravel 8**:

`@yield` can have default content as a second parameter. It can either be a string or a view file

```
// user-layout.blade.php
@yield('header', View::make('layouts.header'))
```

You can now override this "header" with `section`

```
@section('header')
  <div>New Header</div>
@endsection

//// OR - you can also pass a view file as a second parameter //////

@section('header', View::make('layouts.new-header'))
```